# Percent sign (% or %25) is not working in path

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect users from:

`http://example.com/search?poster=ABC123` to `http://example.com/name/ABC123`

In the `$_GET['poster']` variable I also allow the user to enter a wildcard search (%). This is where the problem comes. When the user enters a `%` (converts to `%25`) as the first letter in the path, it gives me an error like this:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /name/%25test on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

However, using the wildcard anywhere else in the string works fine.

Here is my .htaccess file.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteBase /search
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-l
RewriteRule ^name/(.+)$ /?poster=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/(.+)$ /?content=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^title/(.+)$ /?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Examples (my real website):

```
http://archive.rookstat.net/name/%25he <--- Error
http://archive.rookstat.net/name/he%25 <--- Works
http://archive.rookstat.net/name/hello <--- Works
```

How can I resolve this? I've tried many different combinations in the RewriteRule but I must be doing something wrong. Are the flags incorrect? Not always is the user entering a wildcard. So I do not want to use a rule that specifically looks for a "%" or "%25", but in case the user does enter that, it should not think it's a folder or file... or whatever.

I also get the same error with the /search/ path:

```
http://archive.rookstat.net/search/?poster=%he
```

It seems as if it thinks it's a file path, and not a url...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percent(%) symbol is reserved for url encoded characters. I would recommend base64 encoding the entered search term and then decoding in your search function

```
$query = base64_encode($wildcard_query);

$search_term = base64_decode($_GET['poster']);
```

Comment: if your are using mySQL queries , be careful not to enter user defined queries directly into your database since you could open yourself up to  SQL injection attacks.

SEE: [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: yes, i am using pdo with prepared statements to get the data out

Answer (score 0):

Please try the `B` flag to re-encode the backreferences

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

(the example on the documentation matches exactly your use-case and I could not explain it better).

Comment: I tried that but it is still not working. I tried with just [B] and with the others as well.